# DocuSign - Get signed documents body from Java SDK listStatusChanges()

Tags: docusignapi

I must use EnvelopeAPI.listStatusChanges() to poll signed envelopes. It provides an object EnvelopeInfo, containig a List.
For each Envelupe I would like to retrive the signed documents' body, but the Envelope.getEnvelopeDocuments() just return null.

```java
   ListStatusChangesOptions opt = api.new ListStatusChangesOptions();        
   opt.setFromDate(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(lastPoll.minusDays(1)));
   EnvelopesInformation info = api.listStatusChanges(authService.getAccountId(),opt);
   List<Envelope> envList = info.getEnvelopes();
   assert (envList != null);
   for (Envelope env : envList) {
       String envId = env.getEnvelopeId());
       String status = env.getStatus();
       LocalDateTime changeTime = LocalDateTime.from(
                     DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
                     .parse(env.getStatusChangedDateTime()));
       System.out.format("%s: Changed status of \"%s\" in %s\n",
                        changeTime.toString(), envId(),status());
       if (status.equals("completed")) {
           List<EnvelopeDocument> documents =  env.getEnvelopeDocuments();
           assert(documents != null);
       }
   }
```

In the example, the last assert on documents always fails. What am I doing wrong?

The only relevat log I got is:

```
TraceToken: de41cfce-8a4d-4ef4-9a5f-a47659fa16fd
Timestamp: 2021-11-09T10:17:19.5448174Z

GET https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<xxx>/envelopes?from_date=2021-11-08T11%3A14%3A13.8906278
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/3.15.0/java
X-DocuSign-SDK: Java
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 93.34.235.164

200 OK

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9671
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: de41cfce-8a4d-4ef4-9a5f-a47659fa16fd

{
  "resultSetSize": "6",
  "startPosition": "0",
  "endPosition": "5",
  "totalSetSize": "6",
  "nextUri": "",
  "previousUri": "",
  "envelopes": [
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/recipients",
      "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/attachments",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2",
      "emailSubject": "Documents to sign",
      "envelopeId": "fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2",
      "signingLocation": "online",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/notification",
      "allowMarkup": "false",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-11-08T11:28:58.4730000Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-08T11:28:58.4730000Z",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2021-11-08T11:29:17.5000000Z",
      "sentDateTime": "2021-11-08T11:28:59.0500000Z",
      "completedDateTime": "2021-11-08T11:29:54.1470000Z",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-11-08T11:29:54.1470000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/fe3b2d69-1671-49cb-9af9-4186f0777ae2/templates",
      "expireEnabled": "true",
      "expireAfter": "120",
      "sender": {
        "userName": "Michele Bert",
        "userId": "xxx",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "email": "michele.bert@xxx.it"
      },
      "purgeState": "unpurged",
      "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
      "autoNavigation": "true",
      "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
      "anySigner": null,
      "envelopeLocation": "not_specified"
    },
    {
      "status": "sent",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/recipients",
      "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/attachments",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb",
      "emailSubject": "Sottoscrizione  Mario Rossi",
      "emailBlurb": "Buongiorno,\ncome da accordi sono a inviarti la proposta di investimento da sottoscrivere.\nTi ricordo che la proposta ha una validità di 48 ore dalla data di consegna.\n\nCordiali saluti\n",
      "envelopeId": "fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb",
      "signingLocation": "online",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/notification",
      "allowMarkup": "false",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-11-09T07:15:48.6970000Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-09T07:17:00.6830000Z",
      "sentDateTime": "2021-11-09T07:17:01.4670000Z",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-11-09T07:17:01.4670000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/fb263fbd-6842-48fa-9665-03df9af2accb/templates",
      "expireEnabled": "true",
      "expireAfter": "2",
      "sender": {
        "userName": "Andrea Debortoli",
        "userId": "xxx",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "email": "andrea.debortoli@xxx.it"
      },
      "purgeState": "unpurged",
      "envelopeIdStamping": "true",
      "autoNavigation": "true",
      "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
      "anySigner": null,
      "envelopeLocation": "not_specified"
    },
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/recipients",
      "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/attachments",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7",
      "emailSubject": "Documents to sign",
      "envelopeId": "3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7",
      "signingLocation": "online",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/notification",
      "allowMarkup": "false",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:28:23.3930000Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:28:23.3930000Z",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:28:43.6400000Z",
      "sentDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:28:23.9730000Z",
      "completedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:29:24.9800000Z",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:29:24.9800000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/3d7130d7-b5bb-4579-9c25-f525c22064e7/templates",
      "expireEnabled": "true",
      "expireAfter": "120",
      "sender": {
        "userName": "Michele Bert",
        "userId": "xxx",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "email": "michele.bert@xxx.it"
      },
      "purgeState": "unpurged",
      "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
      "autoNavigation": "true",
      "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
      "anySigner": null,
      "envelopeLocation": "not_specified"
    },
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/recipients",
      "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/attachments",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a",
      "emailSubject": "Documents to sign",
      "envelopeId": "99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a",
      "signingLocation": "online",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/notification",
      "allowMarkup": "false",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:09.1130000Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:09.1130000Z",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:26.5430000Z",
      "sentDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:10.0370000Z",
      "completedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:53.7670000Z",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:53.7670000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/99f3a387-f8e8-4763-9b50-3c2e49fc536a/templates",
      "expireEnabled": "true",
      "expireAfter": "120",
      "sender": {
        "userName": "Michele Bert",
        "userId": "xxx",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "email": "michele.bert@xxx.it"
      },
      "purgeState": "unpurged",
      "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
      "autoNavigation": "true",
      "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
      "anySigner": null,
      "envelopeLocation": "not_specified"
    },
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/recipients",
      "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/attachments",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4",
      "emailSubject": "Documents to sign",
      "envelopeId": "864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4",
      "signingLocation": "online",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/notification",
      "allowMarkup": "false",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:58:49.7900000Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:58:49.7900000Z",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:59:06.0800000Z",
      "sentDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:58:50.4330000Z",
      "completedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:59:37.2700000Z",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-11-09T09:59:37.2700000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/864d7b45-e5a2-4188-a5c3-52693a2909c4/templates",
      "expireEnabled": "true",
      "expireAfter": "120",
      "sender": {
        "userName": "Michele Bert",
        "userId": "xxx",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "email": "michele.bert@xxx.it"
      },
      "purgeState": "unpurged",
      "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
      "autoNavigation": "true",
      "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
      "anySigner": null,
      "envelopeLocation": "not_specified"
    },
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "documentsUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/documents",
      "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/recipients",
      "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/attachments",
      "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce",
      "emailSubject": "Documents to sign",
      "envelopeId": "f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce",
      "signingLocation": "online",
      "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/custom_fields",
      "notificationUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/notification",
      "allowMarkup": "false",
      "createdDateTime": "2021-11-09T10:14:16.2630000Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-09T10:14:16.2800000Z",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2021-11-09T10:14:36.8400000Z",
      "sentDateTime": "2021-11-09T10:14:17.5300000Z",
      "completedDateTime": "2021-11-09T10:15:11.1630000Z",
      "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-11-09T10:15:11.1630000Z",
      "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/documents/combined",
      "certificateUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/documents/certificate",
      "templatesUri": "/envelopes/f01ef821-b29c-4747-804d-b379644b9bce/templates",
      "expireEnabled": "true",
      "expireAfter": "120",
      "sender": {
        "userName": "Michele Bert",
        "userId": "xxx",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "email": "michele.bert@xxx.it"
      },
      "purgeState": "unpurged",
      "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
      "autoNavigation": "true",
      "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
      "anySigner": null,
      "envelopeLocation": "not_specified"
    }
  ]
}
```

The call to Envelope.getEnvelopeDocuments() does not seem to end up in any REST calls. I expected it to request the document list at the URI contained in Envelope.documentsUri field. Am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the documents info to be retrieved, the request property *include* must contain "documents", as stated  at [1]. From the java SDK point of view, it correspond to call

```
listStatusChangesOptions.setInclude("documents,...");
```

Where the *...* states for any other detail type you need to retrieve (in my case, for example, I need also the list of recipients, so I set "recipients, documents").

Then, on Envelope objects returned by the request, the getEnvelopeDocuments() method can be called, which return a list of *Document* objects. Such objects contain all the summary information, included the "documentUri", in a form like:

```
/envelopes/c34c029d-1074-4h66-afe1-324b851397c4/documents/1
```

which, concatenated to the basepath, forms exactly the URL of the REST API to download a document. In other words, using this URI or the *EnvelopesApi.getDocument()* are exactly the same things.

The conclusion is that there are no way to download documents, without down-counting at least one call from the per-hour available

[1] https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what `env.getEnvelopeDocuments()` is doing.

You should be using the [EnvelopeDocuments:get](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) API method.

Here is a [code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/eSignature/examples/EG007ControllerEnvelopeGetDoc.java#L81) of calling the API method from Java.

```
byte[] results = envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId);
```

To get all the documents combined into one document, use the reserved value `"combined"` as the documentId.

Comment: That's the same doubt I have: what does the method [Envelope.getEnvelopeDocuments()](https://javadoc.io/static/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java/3.16.0-RC1/com/docusign/esign/model/Envelope.html#getEnvelopeDocuments()) do? I expected it to return the list of Documents object contained in the envelope (without scaling the API call from the per-hour amount available, I hoped)